# Is garbage collection affecting the framerate of this canvas snake game?

Tags: javascript, canvas, garbage-collection

[**JSFiddle demo (~200 lines. WASD to move, snake speed is set to very slow)**](https://jsfiddle.net/qf3upqrs/)

Whenever I let my code run for a while, I can observe the framerate steadily declining.

I believe the code that is rendering the snake contributes to the fps loss: it clears the entire canvas using `ctx.clearRect`. It then takes a one-dimensional array representing x and y cordinates of turns that the snake takes and creates a path. I then call `ctx.stroke`. It would be better to only draw the new part of the snake, as opposed to clearing the canvas and remaking the path of the entire snake and redrawing that snake on each frame, right?

```
Snake.prototype.render = function() {

// this.env.canvas.fgContext is the context for the foreground canvas.
// There is a background canvas for a chess background pattern.
this.env.canvas.fgContext.strokeStyle = this.color;
this.env.canvas.fgContext.lineWidth   = this.env.tileSize;
this.env.canvas.fgContext.lineCap = "square";
this.env.canvas.fgContext.beginPath();
this.env.canvas.fgContext.moveTo(this.env.leftWidthGap + (this.positions[0]-0.5)*this.env.tileSize,
                                 this.env.topHeightGap + (this.positions[1]-0.5)*this.env.tileSize);

for(var i = 2; i < this.positions.length; i += 2)
   this.env.canvas.fgContext.lineTo(this.env.leftWidthGap + (this.positions[i]-0.5)*this.env.tileSize,
                                 this.env.topHeightGap + (this.positions[i+1]-0.5)*this.env.tileSize);
this.env.canvas.fgContext.stroke();
}
```

Also, the code that moves the "head" and "tail" of the snake seem to be negatively impacting the framerate, as removing it (as well as removing the rendering code) results in no framerate loss:

```
Snake.prototype.moveHead = function(delta) {
this.idx    = this.positions.length - (this.input.isCurrentY ? 1 : 2),
this.newPos = this.positions[this.idx] + this.speed * delta * this.input.currentDir;

if(this.input.currentKeyCode === this.input.futureKeyCode || Math.trunc(this.positions[this.idx]) === Math.trunc(this.newPos)) { this.positions[this.idx] = this.newPos; return; }
this.positions[this.idx] = Math.round(this.positions[this.idx]);
this.deltaChange = Math.abs(this.newPos - this.positions[this.idx]);
this.input.assignFutureToCurrent();
this.inputStack.push(this.input.currentDir)
this.inputStack.push(this.input.isCurrentY);
this.positions.push(this.positions[this.positions.length-2]);
this.positions.push(this.positions[this.positions.length-2]);
this.positions[this.positions.length - (this.input.isCurrentY ? 1 : 2)] += this.deltaChange * this.input.currentDir;
}
Snake.prototype.moveTail = function(delta) {
this.idx = this.inputStack[1] ? 1 : 0;
this.positions[this.idx] += this.speed * delta * this.inputStack[0];

if((this.inputStack[0] < 0 && this.positions[this.idx] < this.positions[this.idx+2]) ||
    this.inputStack[0] > 0 && this.positions[this.idx] > this.positions[this.idx+2]) {
    this.deltaChange = Math.abs(this.positions[this.idx] - this.positions[this.idx+2]);
    this.positions = this.positions.slice(2),
    this.inputStack = this.inputStack.slice(2);
    this.positions[this.inputStack[1] ? 1 : 0] += this.deltaChange * this.inputStack[0];
}
}
```

These functions are called on every frame in a game loop that I can elaborate on if necessary. Is the problem all the pushing and slicing of arrays? Is memory leaking here?

Comment: Yes, right. To check if the memory is leaking, have a look at your me  usage

Comment: Use Chrome's new performance monitor in DevTools. Click customize (top right icon (3 Dots in a column)) => More tools => Performance monitor and you can see all you need (there is no memory leak, it very hard to create a memory leak in javascript. A memory leak is memory you can not free, not memory you use and don't free)

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code. However things can be done to improve performance.

I'd recommend being careful when you use .push(), that will cause the size of your array to grow which can affect performance if left unchecked. Another option is to replace divisions with multiplications as they are cheaper operations.